# parsing JSON messages with Spark Streaming in Python

Tags: json, pyspark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Dstream of JSON messages of the form `{"UserID": "Xxxx", "Count": 000}`. I want to figure out the best way to parse it so that I can create a data frame.

What's the difference between 1 and 2 in this case:

1. `parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))`
2. `parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])`

Comment: Have you tried them?

Answer (score 3):

This is KafkaStream specific question.  You are receiving PAIR RDD from the Kafka DSstream.  A pair rdd is two elements tuple (key, value).  This is why you have to pick the 2nd element to retrieve the value.  I would write

```
parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda (key, value): json.loads(value))
```

In Python it's recommended to use `_` for unused variable, but in this case I'd use `key` to remind me the lambda is receiving the pair RDD.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `json.loads(x)` the string (your message) is parsed into a dictionary, not sure what you're trying to do with `json.loads(x[1])`, but if you want the value of the first key of the dictionary you should go for `json.loads(x)["UserId"]`. Not sure if this is what you haven't understood.

Example:

```
import json

raw = """{
    "UserId": "Xxx", 
    "Count": "0000"
}"""

print(type(raw))
print(raw)

parsed = json.loads(raw)

print(type(parsed))
print(parsed)

parsed_partial = json.loads(raw)["UserId"]

print(type(parsed_partial))
print(parsed_partial)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
{
    "UserId": "Xxx", 
    "Count": "0000"
}
<class 'dict'>
{'UserId': 'Xxx', 'Count': '0000'}
Xxx
```

For understanding `map()` read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

Comment: Thank you jlnabais. I think my question was not properly worded/tagged since i am very new to both stack overflow, python, kafka and spark streaming. I wanted to understand how a json message consumed by spark streaming from kafka as a Dstream was being parsed. In this case will json.loads(x[0]) be the offset and json.loads(x[1]) be the message containing {"UserID": "Xxxx", "Count": 000}